# Android MediaPlayer plays song twice

Tags: java, android, media-player

I'm making a simple splash screen so that when an app loads it shows a small logo and plays a little jingle.

I've set it up as so:

```
    splashSong = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.splash);
    splashSong.start();
    Thread splashThread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(6000);
            }
            }catch (InterruptedException e){

            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent openMenu = new Intent("com.mmm.MAINMENU");
                startActivity(openMenu);
            }
        }

    };
    splashThread.start();
```

However there is an issue with the play count. When it loads the splash class, the jingle is played twice. I've changed a series of things such as preparing the song and setting the datasource. This is, however, not successful and the screen still plays the song twice.

Anybody have any ideas as to why it might be doing this?

Thanks,

Comment: In what event is the code located?

Comment: do you change your acitivity orientation ?

Comment: To Renan, it happens in this activity.

To Mr.Me, I change the orientation to landscape. Could this be an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Mr. Me](https://stackoverflow.com/users/951448/mr-me) for the help. It was to do with the applications orientation. Removed that and all worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
Add 
splashSong.setLooping(false);
```